# Apart from a US visa what do I need for travel from state to state?

Tags: visas, usa, airport-security, t-and-t-citizens

I'm from Trinidad and Tobago and I possess a valid US visa. I'm travelling to Minnesota and have have several connection flights to get there. Do I need anything other than the visa?

Comment: Your passport is sufficient ID for domestic flights.

Comment: We really should have a canonical question on ID requirements for US domestic flights; it would take care of lots of duplicates.

Comment: US visas are solely for entry to the US. They are irrelevant when you are already inside the US.

Answer (score 3):

You will need your passport (or another [acceptable form of identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), but a passport is the most likely document for a foreign visitor to be carrying). Since your visa is most likely inside your passport, you're probably all set.

Comment: In fact, the visa doesn't need to be in the passport as the visa is not necessary for domestic travel.

Comment: @phoog Indeed. I just mentioned that because the OP said he had the visa, and since visas are almost always inside passports, he's probably got everything he needs to travel right there.